# restoring Tensorflow model: cannot find gamma/scale for batch_norm layers in the checkpoint file

Tags: tensorflow, restore, checkpoint, batch-normalization

I am able to restore a model and extract parameters for weights, biases and batch_norm layers from checkpoint files.
However for multiple checkpoint files (inception models etc.), I cannot find the scaling/gamma factor of the BN layer.

For example, in the public inceptionV3 checkpoint, I can locate:
`InceptionV3/Mixed_5d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean (DT_FLOAT) [64]`
`InceptionV3/Mixed_5d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance (DT_FLOAT) [64]`
`InceptionV3/Mixed_5d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/beta (DT_FLOAT) [64]`

However, there is nothing such as `InceptionV3/Mixed_5d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma`.

How can I get the gamma value or it is rescaled to 1 by default?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So most of the network uses the batch_norm from SLIM which by default without scaling/gamma parameter.

scale: If True, multiply by `gamma`. If False, `gamma` is
      not used. When the next layer is linear (also e.g. `nn.relu`), this can be
      disabled since the scaling can be done by the next layer.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L365-L386

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the pretrained inceptionV2 of the slim library.

First I was using this arg_scope, i got that problem:

```
def _batch_norm_arg_scope(list_ops,
                          use_batch_norm=True,
                          batch_norm_decay=0.9997,
                          batch_norm_epsilon=0.001,
                          batch_norm_scale=False,
                          train_batch_norm=False):
    """Slim arg scope for InceptionV2 batch norm."""
    if use_batch_norm:
        batch_norm_params = {
            'is_training': train_batch_norm,
            'scale': batch_norm_scale,
            'decay': batch_norm_decay,
            'epsilon': batch_norm_epsilon
        }
        normalizer_fn = slim.batch_norm
    else:
        normalizer_fn = None
        batch_norm_params = None

    return slim.arg_scope(list_ops,
                          normalizer_fn=normalizer_fn,
                          normalizer_params=batch_norm_params)
```

I solved using the arg_scope in the slim library.

```
with slim.arg_scope(inception_v2.inception_v2_arg_scope()):
```

that simply is:

```
def inception_arg_scope(weight_decay=0.00004,
                        use_batch_norm=True,
                        batch_norm_decay=0.9997,
                        batch_norm_epsilon=0.001,
                        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu):
  """Defines the default arg scope for inception models.

  Args:
    weight_decay: The weight decay to use for regularizing the model.
    use_batch_norm: "If `True`, batch_norm is applied after each convolution.
    batch_norm_decay: Decay for batch norm moving average.
    batch_norm_epsilon: Small float added to variance to avoid dividing by zero
      in batch norm.
    activation_fn: Activation function for conv2d.

  Returns:
    An `arg_scope` to use for the inception models.
  """
  batch_norm_params = {
      # Decay for the moving averages.
      'decay': batch_norm_decay,
      # epsilon to prevent 0s in variance.
      'epsilon': batch_norm_epsilon,
      # collection containing update_ops.
      'updates_collections': tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS,
      # use fused batch norm if possible.
      'fused': None,
  }
  if use_batch_norm:
    normalizer_fn = slim.batch_norm
    normalizer_params = batch_norm_params
  else:
    normalizer_fn = None
    normalizer_params = {}
  # Set weight_decay for weights in Conv and FC layers.
  with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                      weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)):
    with slim.arg_scope(
        [slim.conv2d],
        weights_initializer=slim.variance_scaling_initializer(),
        activation_fn=activation_fn,
        normalizer_fn=normalizer_fn,
        normalizer_params=normalizer_params) as sc:
      return sc
```